# Pandas change value if muliple conditions across multiple rows are met

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python and pandas to check student's academic histories. I want to count the number of passes a student has got. The history might look something like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Course': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E','F','G'],
        'Result': ['Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass','Fail','Pass'],
        'Superseded_by':['E','E','F','F','','','H']        
     })
print(df)

  Course Result Superseded_by
0      A   Pass             E
1      B   Fail             E
2      C   Pass             F
3      D   Fail             F
4      E   Pass              
5      F   Fail              
6      G   Pass             H
```

The problem is that older courses get superseded by newer ones and so my code mustn't count both. So I want to alter a Course's Result to 'Superseded' if and only if

- The Course Result is Passed
- The Course in the Superseded_by column exists in the student record
- The Superseded_by course is also Passed

The output of running this would look like this

```
  Course      Result Superceded_by
0      A  Superceded             E
1      B        Fail             E
2      C        Pass             F
3      D        Fail             F
4      E        Pass              
5      F        Fail              
6      G        Pass             H
```

Course A is Passed, is superseded by E, which is also Passed. All other courses fail the test so remain unchanged.
I have done multiple conditions before but not across different rows.
Note I am not changing a student's official record so changing the Result column is appropriate in this context.
What is the most efficient way I can do this?

Comment: Can there be several levels of superceding? (A -> E -> G -> H)

Comment: @mozway in theory it is possible, in practice I don't think there are any so atm I'd be happy with a single level check

Comment: OK, the below approach should work for both but will stop at each Fail in case of a complex Pass* -> Pass -> Fail -> Pass* -> Pass -> Fail (* = superceded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify passed courses and use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to select rows in which the course is passed and the superseding course is also passed:

```
passed = df.loc[df['Result'].eq('Pass'), 'Course']
# ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G']
          
df.loc[df['Result'].eq('Pass')
     & df['Superseded_by'].isin(passed),
     'Result'] = 'Superseded'
```

Output:

```
   Course       Result Superseded_by
0       A   Superseded             E
1       B         Fail             E
2       C         Pass             F
3       D         Fail             F
4       E         Pass              
5       F         Fail              
6       G         Pass             H
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

**Step1**

make mapper(dictionary)

```
m = dict(df[['Course', 'Result']].values)
```

`m`

```
{'A': 'Pass','B': 'Fail', 'C': 'Pass', 'D': 'Fail', 'E': 'Pass','F': 'Fail','G': 'Pass'}
```

**Step2**

make codition

1. Result column == 'Pass'
2. Superseded_by column after mapping by `m` == 'Pass'

condition = 1 & 2

```
cond = df['Result'].eq('Pass') & df['Superseded_by'].map(m).eq('Pass')
```

**Step3**

booleanmasking to Result column by `cond`

```
df.assign(Result=df['Result'].mask(cond, 'Superceded'))
```

output:

```
Course  Result  Superseded_by
0   A   Superceded  E
1   B   Fail        E
2   C   Pass        F
3   D   Fail        F
4   E   Pass    
5   F   Fail    
6   G   Pass        H
```